# How to call in form load the gridview cell click

Tags: winforms, gridview

I have gridviewname_CellClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e) event. I want this event to be called in Form load.

When i try

gridviewname_CellClick(sender,e)- i get exception as e as not an event of GridViewCellEventArgs, how to call this on form load?

Any inputs?

Comment: Which cell do you want to simulate a click of?

Comment: Do you mean `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. I suggest that you put your codes from GrisViewName_Click in another function then call that in your form load & GrisViewName_Click events.

Comment: Thanks hallie i did as you suggested , it worked fine. Thanks.  I will also wait what SLaks approach would be. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not call event handlers directly.
Instead, you should move the event handler code to a separate function, then call that function in the handler and wherever else you want.

To answer the question, you need to create your own `GridViewCellEventArgs` instance and pass it to the handler function.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, Do you have any small sample so that i can refer and create mine (C#).

Comment: What on earth do you mean? `new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, 3)`?